# Import class from nested module in Python

Tags: python, class, import, module

Assuming I have the following file structure:

```
foo (folder)
|
|- bar(folder)
   |
   |- __init__.py
   |- some_class.py
|
|- somefile.py
|- __init__.py
```

Now assuming `some_class` contains a class named `SomeClass`, and I want to import `SomeClass` to `somefile`.

How do I do that?

I tried:

- `from bar import some_class`
- `from bar.some_class import SomeClass`
- `from . import bar.some_class.SomeClass`
- `import bar.some_class`

And nothing works.

Comment: try `from foo.bar.some_class import SomeClass` ?

Comment: @azro No module named 'foo'

Comment: from foo.bar.some_class import SomeClass

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try `sys.path.append`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path')
import some_class
```